# Access a host server running on localhost from a guest VM? (XP-Mode)

Tags: windows-7, localhost, loopback, windows

I have a weblogic server running on localhost, and I'd like to connect to it from an XP-mode virtual machine without much hassle. It isn't accessible via its IP, so I've been trying to get the XP-mode instance to somehow connect directly to the hosts instance of localhost.

I tried setting up a loopback adapter in the host, and navigating to the loopback ID, but that didn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: how is configured weblogic to serve requests ?  can you ping the interfaces ?

Comment: I didn't setup the weblogic configuration - it's all handled as part of an elaborate build process. I can ping the host machine from the guest machine, but I can't connect. Ideally, I wouldn't need to modify this configuration to do this kind of testing. I'd rather do whatever it takes to make the VM act as if it's the host machine.

Comment: Is there a firewall on the host machine?